# How to return the same name of raster after calculations?

Tags: r, raster

I am doing some calculation for rasters and then i want to write them again.

my real data can be read as:

```
dir2<- list.files("C:\\Users", "*.img", full.names = TRUE)
> dir2
[1] "C:\\Users\\fg05102012H_MEAN.img"
........
stackS <- stack(dir2)
```

example data:

```
r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10);
# Populate them with some values
 r1 <- setValues(r1,runif(100,min=1,max=100));
 r2 <- setValues(r2,runif(100,min=1,max=100));
  r3 <- setValues(r3,runif(100,min=1,max=100));
  # Stack them
  st1 <- stack(r1,r2,r3)
  x <- st1 * 0.3
  d2 <- writeRaster(x, ' outputFile.envi ', bylayer=TRUE, overwrite=TRUE)
```

this will write files as `outputFile_1.envi outputFile_2.envi` etc in my current directory.

for me I want to return the same name of the original raster but change the extension from `.img to .envi` and put all of them in a different directory:

```
    outputDir  <- "C:\\data"
    outputFile <- file.path(outputDir, basename(dir2))
```

any idea on how we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this

```
outputDir  <- "C:\\data"
outputFile <- file.path(outputDir, basename(dir2))
extension(outputFile) <- '.envi'
d2 <- writeRaster(x, outputFile, bylayer=TRUE)
```